# Поведение адаптивного дизайна

Tags: css

Вот песочница https://jsfiddle.net/o82kLqdn/1/ Там есть боди с размером 600рх, в нём контейнер 521рх в котором три блока по 164рх с отступами по 10рх. Я всё это сделал резиновым, т.е. делил внутренние блоки на внешние получал размер. Теперь при получении нужных размеров всё работает и размер остался таким каким должен быть. Но когда я сужáю размер окна последний блок вылетает... из-за чего такое поведение ведь всё держалось на месте.

```css
body{
    max-width:600px;
    border:1px black solid;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#wraped{
    border:1px black solid;
    width:86.833%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#block{
    width:31.477%;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    margin-right:1.919%;
    display:inline-block;
}
#block:last-of-type{
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
 <div id="wraped">
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Размер элемента body указан как абсолютный/статичный. Вообще-то к этому элементу не применяют размеры. Если это вам так уж необходимо, то примените относительный размер в %. Размер селектора стилей wraped (родитель блоков) = 86.833%. Если эту цифру разделить на три (количество блоков в контейнере), то получиться примерно 28%, но не 31.477% - как у вас. И ву-а-ля:

```css
body{
    border:1px black solid;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#wraped{
    border:1px black solid;
    width:86.833%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#block{
    width:28%;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    margin-right:1.919%;
    display:inline-block;
}
#block:last-of-type{
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wraped">
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, но нужно чтобы контейнер для #wraped был 600рх

Comment: Укажите кoнтейнер в %